# web3.js installation problem

Tags: web3js, installation

I've ran into a problem trying to install web3.  I went through here and stackover flow to try and solve the issue but had no success. I had to install python2.7 but still getting this error.  Any ideas where I am going wrong? Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
    options.duplicate_basename_check)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1916, in CalculateVariables
    generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 434, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
    versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
KeyError: '2017'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Mark\Documents\GBR\GBCoin\node_modules\sha3
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN gc@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN gc@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sha3@1.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sha3@1.2.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: It seems you haven't configured [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Comment: And prepare yourself for a nightmare (unless you're lucky enough to have all the related stuff which was previously installed on your machine, configured precisely as `windows-build-tools` wants it to be; I once to reinstall Windows 10 completely from scratch in order to make it work).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved the issue. Also found this article for reference incase there are any other problems https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/